# Display encrypted message on frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am currently have a lot of 3D models in obj/ctm format in database, which will be transferred to browser and displayed with javascript. It's known that all javascript code are visible to everybody, although it can be hard to read. I am wondering if there is an encryption algorithm, that can  prevent user accessing raw data in model file, such as vertex array.

Comment: If it's in JavaScript, I can *absolutely* use my browser console and get at all the data in it.

Comment: So does that mean I can't actually secure my data?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to stop someone from being able to get at the vertex array of your model if it's rendered in JavaScript. Although this is true for other media as well (for example, extracting models from games, or downloading/debugging an .swf).

Comment: Once it's client side, there isn't really much you can do to keep the user from doing what they want with the data. Even if you encrypted the data, you'd have to decrypt it to display it, and that means that the decryption key must also be client side. Best you can do is use some kind of obfusicated or custom format that will make it difficult, but not impossible, to get the model. Or do all the rendering server side (slow).

Comment: I would do one of two things if I were building this and it needed a preview function,  1) render preview server side and send images, or 2) send a low-poly/quality model for preview.

Comment: @Minimalist "So does that mean I can't actually secure my data?" If by "secure [your] data" you mean "prevent users from reading it", then yes - the user agent *needs to read* the data to be able to use it. Trying to hide assets the user needs is like saying "I want people to read this book, but I don't want people to read the words".